# Automorphism on finitely generated field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

> Show that the complex numbers $i\sqrt{3}$ and $1+i\sqrt{3}$ are roots of $f(x) = x^{4}-2x^{3} + 7x^{2} - 6x + 12$. Let $K$ be the field generated by $\mathbb{Q}$ and the roots of $f$. Is there an automorphism $\sigma$ of $K$ with $\sigma(i\sqrt{3}) = 1 + \sqrt{3}$?

The first part is easy. For the second, I tried calculate
$$[\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3},-i\sqrt{3},1 + i\sqrt{3},1-i\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]$$
but I couldn't advance. I don't know if this is the best way. Any hint?

*Update.* In fact, automorphism does not have to fix $\mathbb{Q}$, right?

Comment: If $\sigma(\alpha)=\beta$ then $\sigma(\alpha^2)=\beta^2$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, $\sigma$ need to fix $\mathbb{Q}$? If yes, I know how to use your hint, because $\sigma(-3) \in \mathbb{C}$. But $\sigma$ it is not necessarily an $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism. I guess I got it wrong. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: In a field of characteristic $0$, any field automorphism fixes $\mathbf Q$. Actually any field automorphism fixes its prime field  (by definition of a prime field) – $\mathbf Q$ in characteristic $0$ or $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ in characteristic $p$.

Comment: @Bernard, thanks!